# If $f(x_n)$ converges for all bounded continuous functions $f$, does then $x_n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $x_n\in \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_n) \longrightarrow f(x)$ (as $n \longrightarrow \infty$) for all bounded continuous functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Do we then have $x_n \longrightarrow x$ (as $n \longrightarrow \infty$)?

Comment: Take $\displaystyle f(y)=\frac{1}{1+(y-x)^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose otherwise. Then there is an an interval $(x-a,x+a)$ such that $x_n\notin(x-a,x-a)$ for infinitely many $n$'s. Define$$f(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x+a&\text{ if }y\geqslant x+a\\y&\text{ if }y\in(x-a,x+a)\\x-a&\text{ if }y\leqslant x-a.\end{array}\right.$$Then $\bigl|f(x_n)-x\bigr|\geqslant a$ for infinitely many $n$'s and therefore $\lim_n f(x_n)\not\to x = f(x).$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set
$$f_k(t) = t ,\ \ -k<x<k$$
$$f_k(t) = k , \ \ t\geq k$$
$$f_k(t) = -k , \ \ t\leq k$$
for all k. Then for $|k|>x$, we must have some N where all $|x_n|<k$ for all n>N. So for all such n
$$f_k(x_n) = x_n \rightarrow x$$

Comment: The function $f_k$ you defined has a jump at $k;$ so they are not continuous in particular even though they are bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(y)= arctan(y-x)$, Then $f:R \rightarrow (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ is homeomorphism so  $$f(x_n) \longrightarrow f(x) \quad \text{if and only if} \quad x_n \longrightarrow x$$